# The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these

Tags: sql, metadata, sql-server-2014, openrowset

I am migrating from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2014 and one of the queries stopped working in SQL Server 2014:

```
select * 
from openrowset ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;',' exec [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]')
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set,
>   Line 1
>   The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.
>
> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object "#MyTempTable" because it does not exist or you
>   do not have permissions.

`dbo.MyTable` and `#MyTempTable` are not real names.

What could cause this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I realize I'm necroing a 3 year old post but wonder what you expected to happen when you try to run EXEC on a TABLE (MyTable) instead of a stored procedure or a SELECT.  I suspect that's the real problem here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From SQL Server 2012 onwards, you need to use `WITH RESULT SETS` to explicitly describe the result set:

```
EXEC('exec [MyDatabase].[dbo].[StoredProcedure] WITH RESULT SETS (( val SMALLINT));')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that EXEC isn't going to work against a table.  It should be a stored procedure or embedded SELECT statement, the latter of which would make little sense here.

Comment: The answer is based on the question that includes `exec [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]`. As this was working in SQL2005, I can only assume it was a stored procedure in the first place, however, to clarify my answer I have changed it to `[StoredProcedure]`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Jaco.  I figured you figured that but had to say it out loud in case a newbie was reading this forum.  I also forgot to take my hat off to you for the WITH RESULT SETS part of your answer.

Comment: In case this helps anyone in the future, I've wasted a couple days battling with this with a system extended procedure, till I found that you can use "WITH RESULT SETS NONE" too...